# Issue Report not availble for version 5.1.2

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

When running the sonar runner in TeamCity on previous versions of SonarQube it was possible to create an HTML issues report for the analysis. This could then be loaded into a tab on the build to show analysis results. However, since 5.1 the Issues Report plugin has been replaced with built in functionality and has been deprecated.
The report is still created if run in preview mode, but it is not created when run in analysis mode, so that the tab on the build is no longer available.
Can this functionality be made available?

Answer (score 1):

This is a native feature since SQ 5.1, see "[Getting Issues Report in Preview Mode](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Getting+Issues+Report+in+Preview+Mode)"

Comment: the page does not exist anymore